# setTable not working as expected with a legacy database in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a legacy (not written to Cake naming conventions) database on a CakePHP 3.5.13 application.

One of the database tables is named `article_95`.

When I attempted to bake the application it's showing the entity name as `Article95`. It's then producing loads of error messages saying:

```
 Table 'article95' doesn't exist
```

So I've read [CakePHP error: cake bake is using the wrong table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27520065/cakephp-error-cake-bake-is-using-the-wrong-table-name) and [How to use table name different then in database in cake php 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43798764/how-to-use-table-name-different-then-in-database-in-cake-php-3) and decided to do it manually using `setTable()`.

So I have created `src/Model/Table/Article95Table.php` with the following code in it:

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class Article95Table extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->setTable('article_95');
    }
}
```

But it won't seem to recgonise this. In a controller I've created a testing method and done the following:

```
    Cache::clear(false);
    $Article95 = TableRegistry::get('Article95');
    debug($Article95->find()->list());
```

But it's coming up with:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'article95' doesn't exist
```

It's as if it's not reading the `setTable()` method.

I've used the `Cache::clear(false)` to ensure it's not being cached and have inspected the `tmp/cache` directory for any suspect files - nothing relevant in there.

Any ideas?

Equally if I change my `debug()` statement to just `debug($Article95)` I get the following, with the wrong table name:

```
object(Cake\ORM\Table) {

    'registryAlias' => 'Article95',
    'table' => 'article95',
    'alias' => 'Article95',
    'entityClass' => '\Cake\ORM\Entity',
    'associations' => [],
    'behaviors' => [],
    'defaultConnection' => 'default',
    'connectionName' => 'default'

}
```

*Incidentally, if I put a non-existent class/entity name in `TableRegistry::get()` - for example `TableRegistry::get('dsfdsfdsfsd');` it won't produce an error message but will show the object above with the non-existent table name. Surely this is also wrong?*

Comment: Something you're showing here probably isn't what you're actually using. The object that you have there is a so called [**"generic table" or "auto table"**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#disabling-generic-tables), a table object created from `\Cake\ORM\Table`, because the concrete table class `Article95Table` could not be found. The same thing that happens for `dsfdsfdsfsd`.

Comment: How can the concrete table class not be found? There's a file `Article95Table.php` inside the appropriate directory! It's working for other models I've created but `bake` seems to have been happy to work with their naming scheme.

Comment: I can't really tell from here, what you are showing looks correct, but as I said, maybe that's not what you're actually using? Maybe there's a typo in the path, or in the namespace, maybe it's a permission issue, maybe a cache issue in case you're using an opcode cache, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this working so wanted to share my solution.

After some trial and error it seems that appending an 's' to the class name (presumably to make Cake consider it plural?) works.

So I renamed the `Table` class to `Article95sTable.php` and then used the following code inside:

```
class Article95sTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->setTable('article_95'); 
    }
}
```

Now when I call the following it picks up the table correctly:

```
$foo = TableRegistry::get('Article95s');
debug($foo);
```

To confirm this is working if I rename the table inside my `setTable()` method the output will change accordingly.

Comment: Your table class should be called Articles or OldArticles and not have 95 in it :). That way the registry can actually find it and use it.

Comment: Read the original post - I'm working with a legacy database where the table names have not been written to Cake conventions. The above works.

Comment: I know that. The thing is the Table class `name` does _not_ have to be related to the _actual_ db name. You can keep the legacy db tables, but you can still use Cake Naming conventions for your table class. So there is no need to have "95" in the class name if you are using `$this->setTable`. I know what you wrote works, but you would have saved yourself the trouble if you would have named the table class right in the first place. That's all I am saying.